# Impass with Random

Tags: java, random

Hello I am currently making a weird type of game, and for one part of it you get encountered by a monster which is called a rat and to attack I use Random to give out a number inbetween 0-7 to deal damage and well everytime you click its supposed to attack (deal damage) and use the random above to decide how much damage it deals. Everytime it deals damage I want it to subtract from the rat's overall health.

```
int rabbithealth = 23;
Random attack = new Random();   
rabbithealth = rabbithealth - attack.nextInt(7);
```

Now, I know why I'm having trouble. rabbithealth is 23 so it subtracts the random numb each time, so its going to just print rabbithealth - attack i.e , but I want it to subtract from that number instead of 23 each time. In an example
instead of it being 23 - 4 , or 23 - 6 each time i want it to be 23 - 3 then when clicked again 20 - (random number)
here is my code 
    package com.Game.user;

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class Swendiver {

    private JFrame frmSwendiver;
    private JTextField console;
    private JTextField Log;
    private JTextField Weapon;
    private JTextField Arrows;
    private JTextField next;
    private JTextField Class;
    private JTextField Coin;
    private JTextField enemyhealth;
    private JTextField myhealth;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Swendiver window = new Swendiver();
                    window.frmSwendiver.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Swendiver() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmSwendiver = new JFrame();
        frmSwendiver.setResizable(false);
        frmSwendiver.setTitle("Swendiver 1.0");
        frmSwendiver.setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        frmSwendiver.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frmSwendiver.setBounds(100, 100, 623, 406);
        frmSwendiver.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        console = new JTextField();
        console.setBounds(0, 0, 606, 44);
        console.setEditable(false);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(console);
        console.setColumns(10);

        Log = new JTextField();
        Log.setBounds(0, 311, 607, 56);
        Log.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // KeyEvent.getKeyCode(VK_ENTE-R);
            }
        });
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Log);
        Log.setColumns(10);
        JButton button4 = new JButton("Enter");
        button4.setBounds(517, 43, 89, 270);
        JLabel lblHealth = new JLabel("Your Health:");
        lblHealth.setBackground(new Color(50, 205, 50));
        lblHealth.setBounds(275, 93, 100, 27);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblHealth);
        console.setText("Press The enter button to start Swendiver");
        JButton Send = new JButton("Enter");
        Send.setBounds(517, 43, 89, 270);
        Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        Send.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                boolean isClicked = true;
                if (isClicked == true) {
                    isClicked = false;

                    lblHealth.setName("Health: 75%");
                    console.setText("[Hermin] Welcome. Ready for your adventure? (Click Enter)");
                    Send.setVisible(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                Log.setText("");
                ArrayList<String> weapon = new ArrayList<String>();
                console.setText("Ok, choose your weapon. <SWORD>||<BOW>");
                // Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("SWORD")
                // console.setText("Good choice.");
                Log.setText("");
                weapon.add("Sword");
                if (weapon.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Sword")) {
                    console.setText("[Hermin] A sword? I see. Good choice...");
                    next.setText("This box is used for Instructions/Actions");
                }
            }
        });

        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Send);

        JLabel lblWeapon = new JLabel("Weapon:");
        lblWeapon.setBounds(441, 145, 56, 27);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblWeapon);
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Enter");
        button3.setBounds(517, 43, 89, 270);
        Weapon = new JTextField();
        Weapon.setBounds(421, 166, 86, 20);
        Weapon.setEditable(false);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Weapon);
        Weapon.setColumns(10);

        JButton Enter = new JButton("Enter");
        Enter.setBounds(517, 41, 89, 272);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Enter);

        JLabel lblArrows = new JLabel("Arrows:");
        lblArrows.setEnabled(false);
        lblArrows.setBounds(275, 151, 46, 14);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblArrows);

        Arrows = new JTextField();
        Arrows.setEnabled(false);
        Arrows.setBounds(260, 168, 68, 20);
        Arrows.setEditable(false);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Arrows);
        Arrows.setColumns(10);
        Random attack = new Random();
        next = new JTextField();
        next.setBounds(0, 43, 346, 25);
        next.setEditable(false);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(next);
        next.setColumns(10);

        JButton Attack = new JButton("Attack");

        Attack.setBounds(0, 68, 89, 245);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Attack);

        JLabel lblClass = new JLabel("Class:");
        lblClass.setBounds(451, 93, 46, 27);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblClass);

        Class = new JTextField();
        Class.setEditable(false);
        Class.setBounds(421, 114, 86, 20);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Class);
        Class.setColumns(10);
        JLabel swordpic = new JLabel("");
        swordpic.setEnabled(false);
        swordpic.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\IDE\\Swendiver\\bin\\sword-icon.png"));
        swordpic.setBounds(391, 154, 40, 34);

        JLabel bowpic = new JLabel("");
        bowpic.setEnabled(false);
        bowpic.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Crossbow-icon.png"));
        bowpic.setBounds(352, 152, 40, 34);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(bowpic);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(swordpic);
        Coin = new JTextField();
        Coin.setText("78");
        Coin.setEditable(false);
        Coin.setBounds(421, 211, 86, 20);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(Coin);
        Coin.setColumns(10);
        next.setText("");
        JLabel lblCoin = new JLabel("Coin:");
        lblCoin.setBounds(451, 198, 46, 14);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblCoin);
        Enter.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                console.setText("[Hermin]Choose your class <Warrior> or <Archer>");
                if (Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Warrior")) {
                    console.setText("[Hermin]A Swordsman.. I see. Good choice.");
                    Weapon.setText("Sword");
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                    next.setText("Click Enter to continue");
                    Log.setText("");
                    Class.setText("Warrior");
                    Enter.setVisible(false);
                    Enter.setEnabled(false);
                    swordpic.setEnabled(true);
                }
                if (Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Archer")) {
                    console.setText("[Hermin]An Archer.. Interesting. Here are your Items.");
                    Weapon.setText("Long-Bow");
                    Arrows.setText("19");
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                    next.setText("Click Enter to continue");
                    Log.setText("");
                    Class.setText("Archer");
                    lblArrows.setEnabled(true);
                    Arrows.setEnabled(true);
                    Enter.setVisible(false);
                    Enter.setEnabled(false);
                    button3.setEnabled(true);
                    button3.setVisible(true);
                    bowpic.setEnabled(true);
                }
                if (Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("/secretcommand")) {
                    Coin.setText(Integer.toString(300));
                    int Coin = 300;
                    next.setText("222 Coin Aquired");
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                    Log.setText("");
                    next.setText("Click Enter to continue!");
                    Enter.setEnabled(false);
                    Enter.setVisible(false);
                    button3.setVisible(true);
                    button3.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }

        });

        button3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                console.setText("[Hermin] Great. Welcome then. Head into SheildsTown to collect some items.");
                next.setText("/EquipArmor to get geared and go.");
                if (Log.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("/EquipArmor")) {
                    next.setText("You leave the armory.");
                    console.setText("");
                    Log.setText("");
                    button3.setEnabled(false);
                    button3.setVisible(false);
                    button4.setVisible(true);
                    button4.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(button3);

        int rathealth = 23;
        button4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                next.setText("You encounter a rat! Attack it! [Rat Health]: 23");
                console.setText("[You]: Ahh! I shall kill you wretched beast!");
                Attack.setEnabled(true);
                boolean mob = true;
                if (rathealth == 0) {

                    next.setText("You Killed the Rat!");
                    console.setText("I need food for later. </Loot to scavenge monsters or people you kill for items>");
                }

                    }
                });

        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(button4);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enemies health:");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(125, 119, 100, 27);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        enemyhealth = new JTextField();
        enemyhealth.setEditable(false);
        enemyhealth.setBounds(113, 139, 96, 20);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(enemyhealth);
        enemyhealth.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblEnemyDetails = new JLabel("Enemy details");
        lblEnemyDetails.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblEnemyDetails.setBounds(115, 79, 128, 25);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblEnemyDetails);

        JLabel lblYourDetails = new JLabel("Your details");
        lblYourDetails.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblYourDetails.setBounds(389, 55, 129, 41);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblYourDetails);

        myhealth = new JTextField();
        myhealth.setText("           100%");
        myhealth.setEditable(false);
        myhealth.setBounds(257, 114, 100, 20);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(myhealth);
        myhealth.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Commands/input below");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(241, 286, 161, 27);
        frmSwendiver.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        boolean enemydoesdamage = true;
        String middlespacingforhealth = "           ";
        Attack.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            boolean attacksituation = true;
            int noobiesword = attack.nextInt(7);
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (Weapon.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Sword")) {
                //  next.setText("You swing your sword and do: "+ Integer.toString(attack.nextInt()) + " damage");
                    Attack.setEnabled(true);
                    enemyhealth.setText(Integer.toString(rathealth - attack.nextInt(7)));
                //  next.setText("Rat bites, and does: " + Integer.toString(attack.nextInt(9))+" damage");
                    console.setText("[Thought](My arm is dripping blood)");

                    if(enemydoesdamage){
                        int Health = 100;
                        myhealth.setText("           "+ Integer.toString(Health-attack.nextInt(9))+"%");
                    }
                }
                if(Weapon.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Long-Bow")){
                    next.setText("You shoot your bow and do: " + noobiesword);
                    enemyhealth.setText("           " + Integer.toString( rathealth - noobiesword));
                }
                }


        });

}}
```

Comment: Don't recreate the `Random` object each time, make it once and keep re-using it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer if I made it more than once it was to test something, and please only post something that will actually help me. I need an alternate solution to my problem

Comment: Given the nature of `Random`, re-creating it could cause it to return the same values in the same order, over and over again. But if you don't think that is helpful, then you are free to ignore it

Comment: Remember, you are in an Object Oriented language, this means that your `Rabbit` or `Rat` (and possibly even a `Monster`) should be objects, with their own properties and traits. This way you can create multiple instances of these objects and modify their states individually

Comment: Only 350 lines for random internet people to debug? Yeah, I'm going to look at that. I'll get right on it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry, I just realised how rude that last comment came off, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Javam No worries, I have a habit of doing it to ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, Java is a Object Oriented Programming language, this means, you should encapsulating the properties and functionality of your creatures in objects

So, basically, I started with a "base" `Monster` type which describes some of the basic features you might expect (this is pretty basic, you might even consider abstracting it further to a "living thing" which has hit points and can take damage)

```
public interface Monster {
    public int getHitPoints();
    public boolean isDead();
    public int takeDamage(int damage);
    public int performAttack();
}
```

Then I made an abstract version to take care of all the "common" properties, this way I can create other monsters, like `Rabbit`s and `Buggy`s without having to repeat a lot of code...

```
public abstract class AbstractMonster implements Monster {

    private int hitPoints;

    public AbstractMonster(int hitPoints) {
        setHitPoints(hitPoints);
    }

    @Override
    public int getHitPoints() {
        return hitPoints;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDead() {
        return getHitPoints() <= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int takeDamage(int damage) {
        setHitPoints(getHitPoints() - damage);
        return getHitPoints();
    }

    protected void setHitPoints(int hp) {
        hitPoints = hp;
    }

}
```

And finally, my `Rat`!

```
public class Rat extends AbstractMonster {

    public Rat() {
        super(5 + (int) (Math.random() * 15));
    }

    @Override
    public int performAttack() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    }

}
```

Now, each instance of `Rat` will have been 5-20 hit points and do between 0-2 points of damage (I know, vicious).  Now, I've use `Math.random` here for simplicity, but you could use a instance of `Random`, maybe defined in `AbstractMonster`

Then the fight is on!

```
System.out.println("You've been attacked by vicious rat!");
Rat rat = new Rat();
Random rnd = new Random();
do {
    System.out.println("! Whack");
    int damage = rnd.nextInt(4);
    System.out.println("You inflict " + damage + " points of damage on the foul creature");
    if (rat.takeDamage(damage) > 0) {
        System.out.println("The rat attacks and inflicts a merger " + rat.performAttack() + " points of damage on you");
    }
} while (!rat.isDead());
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("The vial vermon has been slain!");
System.out.println("You will forever been known as the 'Slayer of Rats'!");
```

Which might output something like...

```
You've been attacked by vicious rat!
! Whack
You inflict 2 points of damage on the foul creature
The rat attacks and inflicts a merger 0 points of damage on you
! Whack
You inflict 2 points of damage on the foul creature
The rat attacks and inflicts a merger 1 points of damage on you
! Whack
You inflict 3 points of damage on the foul creature
The rat attacks and inflicts a merger 1 points of damage on you
! Whack
You inflict 0 points of damage on the foul creature
The rat attacks and inflicts a merger 1 points of damage on you
! Whack
You inflict 1 points of damage on the foul creature
The rat attacks and inflicts a merger 1 points of damage on you
! Whack
You inflict 2 points of damage on the foul creature
The rat attacks and inflicts a merger 0 points of damage on you
! Whack
You inflict 3 points of damage on the foul creature
The rat attacks and inflicts a merger 0 points of damage on you
! Whack
You inflict 2 points of damage on the foul creature

The vial vermon has been slain!
You will forever been known as the 'Slayer of Rats'!
```

Conceptually what this means is, you could can create as many monsters as you need when you need them, each monster is self contained and manageable

This is a pretty basic concept for Java (and OO) and you really should take the time to learn how you can use it to your advantage